# Need help getting my divs to display inline

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get rows 4 wide using divs. I am trying to just have it be inline going down the page. For some reason, it includes the bottom two in the top row and the middle two on this file are randomly positioned below that, it does not respond to formatting. Keep in mind, the last time I did any code it was back when HTML was still the primary language for all websites. On a side note, if someone could help me understand the necessary jQuery to do a search filter on the user side.

I've tried a couple of different attempts at making it work using tables prior to divs.

```css
.item3 {
  grid-area: main;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: main;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'menu main main main right right';
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 0px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divtablerow">
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <p>NEW 2018 DODGE JOURNEY V6 VALUE PACKAGE</p>
        <p>VIN: 3C4PDCBG1JT508626 STOCK #: 082030</p>
        <p>MSRP$27,385</p>
        <p><a class="buttonGhost" href="#">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gridcontainer">
    <p>NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE ALTITUDE 4X2</p>
    <p>VIN: ZACCJABB4JPH91207 STOCK #: 586043</p>
    <p>MSRP$25,915</p>
    <p><a class="buttonGhost" href="#">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridcontainer">
    <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">
          <p>NEW 2018 DODGE JOURNEY V6 VALUE PACKAGE</p>
          <p>VIN: 3C4PDCBG3JT511401 STOCK #: 082035</p>
          <p>MSRP$27,385</p>
          <p><a class="buttonGhost" href="#">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridcontainer">
        <div class="divTableBody">
          <div class="divtablerow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
              <p>NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE SPORT 4X4</p>
              <p>VIN: ZACCJBAB4JPJ43841 STOCK #: 586049</p>
              <p>MSRP$26,240</p>
              <p><a class="buttonGhost" href="#">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gridcontainer">
      <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableCell">
          <p>NEW 2018 JEEP RENEGADE SPORT 4X4</p>
          <p>VIN: ZACCJBAB3JPJ42826 STOCK #: 586051</p>
          <p>MSRP$26,240</p>
          <p><a class="buttonGhost" href="#">Request internet advertised price.</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gridcontainer">
    <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divtablecell">
        <p>NEW 2019 JEEP COMPASS SPORT FWD</p>
        <p>VIN: 3C4NJCAB8KT615373 STOCK #: 492005</p>
        <p>MSRP$25,285</p>
        <p><a class="buttonGhost" href="#">Request internet 
        advertised price.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Understand where I went wrong with the code and determine the best way to make a 4 wide row for all my parts and pieces.

Comment: By formatting this snippet, it may help you see where your wrapping containers in containers.  Note also that `grid-container` and `gridcontainer` are NOT the same, they are as different as `fred` and `wilma`

Comment: Please show what you have tried for the "filter" here and we can perhaps help there - OR ask an entirely NEW question with that code part with a detailed explanation of your desired filter and where yours fails AND this markup and CSS.

Comment: OH and HTML is STILL the primary, just not the ONLY any more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: grid;` gets applied to direct children of a grid container. In your html there are only 4 direct children to the `grid-container`. That's why you are getting 4 columns. Re-arranging them in your HTML should solve the problem.

For making it responsive you can try using:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(550px, 1fr));
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me a minute to figure out children... like I said, a long time since I coded

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information